# pyspark: how to perform structured streaming using KafkaUtils

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am doing a structured streaming using `SparkSession.readStream` and writing it to hive table, but seems it does not allow me to time-based micro-batches, i.e. I need a batch of 5 secs. All the messages should forms a batch of 5 secs, and the batch data should get written to hive table.
Right now its reading the messages as and when they are being posted to Kafka topic, and each message is one record for the table.
**Working Code**

```
def hive_write_batch_data(data, batchId):
    data.write.format("parquet").mode("append").saveAsTable("test.my_table")

kafka_config = {
        "checkpointLocation":"/user/aiman/temp/checkpoint",
        "kafka.bootstrap.servers":"kafka.bootstrap.server.com:9093",
        "subscribe":"TEST_TOPIC",
        "startingOffsets": offsetValue,
        "kafka.security.protocol":"SSL",
        "kafka.ssl.keystore.location": "kafka.keystore.uat.jks",
        "kafka.ssl.keystore.password": "abcd123",
        "kafka.ssl.key.password":"abcd123",
        "kafka.ssl.truststore.type":"JKS",
        "kafka.ssl.truststore.location": "kafka.truststore.uat.jks",
        "kafka.ssl.truststore.password":"abdc123",
        "kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols":"TLSv1",
        "kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm":""
    }

df = spark.readStream \
              .format("kafka") \
              .options(**kafka_config) \
              .load()
data = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)","offset","timestamp","partition")

data_new = data.select(col("offset"),col("partition"),col("key"),json_tuple(col("value"),"product_code","rec_time")) \
               .toDF("offset","partition","key","product_code","rec_time")

data_new.writeStream. \
        .foreachBatch(hive_write_batch_data) \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

**Problem Statement**
Since each message is being treated as one record entry in hive table, a single *parquet* file is being created for each record, which can trigger hive's small-file issue.

I need to create a time-based batch so that multiple records gets inserted into hive table in one batch. For that I only found `KafkaUtils` to be having support for time-based using `ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)` but it does not create *Dataframes*.
How should I use `KafkaUtils` to create batches read into dataframes ?

Comment: You wouldn't use KafkaUtils. You can create longer trigger durations. See `minOffsetsPerTrigger`, or use sliding windows - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time Alternatively, tools like Apache Goblin are built for this purpose, so you shouldn't need Spark

Comment: @OneCricketeer but `minOffsetsPerTrigger` will fetch the records based on record count. I need to do on the basis of time. Can't use Goblin, since spark is the requirement from client's end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a trigger worked. Added a trigger in the stream writer:

```
data_new.writeStream \
        .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \ #Trigger
        .foreachBatch(hive_write_batch_data) \
        .start() \
        .awaitTermination()
```

Found the article [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spark-trigger-options#:%7E:text=The%20trigger%20option%20enables%20you%20to%20control%20the,as%20it%E2%80%99s%20done%20with%20the%20current%20micro%20batch.)